nav2 - costmap without SLAM map
The map that slam-toolbox is supplying is too noisy. 
I would like to have nav2 construct its costmaps - global and local - using the laserscan only, and to disregard the map the SLAM is supplying. 
What is the way to do it?

Yes, you can set the global costmap to a static size to use relative to your space and populate it only with sensor data. With that said, if its a non-trivial space, your planning will suffer from suboptimality because it won't know about the full space to have the context for finding the best path through non-visible space.

Indeed you can just ise a large,empty global map and let the laser populate it. when obstacles are more or less convexe and sparse it does the job, i have used it for surface véhicules and islands.
